# Visual objects editor

Tags: java, user-interface, testing, ide, edit

I am looking for a tool which will make able to edit parts of Java code visually using something like inspector and place code back.

For example:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Bill Libb");
p.setAge(25);
```

This code should be generated from visual inspector and copied into Java IDE.

This will help quickly create sample objects for testing.

Pros of this approach:

1. Don't need to think what can be changed in object - you see what properties available to change immediately.
2. You don't need to code setting properties - just type the value in the appropriate inspector property.
3. You have a new way of defining/describing object which gives a feeling more that you 
   working with objects rather than with code.

Comment: I know it's not particularly helpful to answer your question by questioning your premises, but I am skeptical that this would really help you create sample objects for testing faster.  A quick script or properties file is almost certainly faster in practice than a clicky GUI sort of interface, unless you're interacting with Swing type UI objects.

Comment: @Jim Kiley, I don't think that quick script is faster. UI gives you a suggestion of what you can change and eliminates the decision time of what you want to change.

Also this changes a way how to do it.

I believe the UI is not used often just because it's expensive to create.

Comment: @Jim Kiley also it could give a feeling that you define/describe objects rather than code them.

Comment: @Jim Kiley, question was helpful to me, I am now understanding the goodness of such tool even better :-)

Comment: Its called editing code.  If you find this hard then you have another problem you are not describing clearly to us

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of testing you're talking about.  I'm also not sure what kind of development you'd be doing where you didn't have a good idea of what properties were available on the objects that you intended to use.  I'm deeply skeptical of your premises.  But, with that said, this might be a good exercise to learn reflection and Swing or another UI framework.

Comment: @Pyrolistical sounds funny :-) But people created things like Intellij IDEA and Autocompletion to make things better rather than using 'vi' :-) I am looking for a way to make development even more human friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Naked Objects](http://www.nakedobjects.org/)?

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop, Yeah I did few years ago. It was several UI and persistence issues. But in general it's very cool system.

But regarding this topic I am looking for a tool which will make me edit the code in a new visual way :-) Naked Objects also considers that your objects are predefined, but I consider that visual inspector will edit any object.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be a GUI tool, but you could easily use reflection to create a program that outputs a properties file with placeholders for a given class's get/set methods. Then you could edit the template property file and load it back in at test time. That way all you need is a text editor, and you could script the creation or population of data in all sorts of interesting ways.